# Python matplotlib subplot only show one figure with imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple colored graphs using matplotlib.
But my problem is that it plots only the last one of my subplot no matter what I try.

I have located another subject with the same title on the forum but it is not the same problem as mine.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_figheight(6)
    fig.set_figwidth(30)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax1.imshow(under10_color, aspect='auto', cmap=colmap, interpolation='nearest')
    ax1.title.set_text('find under 10')
    ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(method_list)))
    ax1.set_xticklabels(method_list)
    ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
    ax1.set_yticklabels(labels)

    ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    ax2.imshow(under20_color, aspect='auto', cmap=colmap, interpolation='nearest')
    ax2.title.set_text('find under 20')
    ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(len(method_list)))
    ax2.set_xticklabels(method_list)
    ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
    ax2.set_yticklabels(labels)

    ax3 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
    ax3.imshow(under50_color, aspect='auto', cmap=colmap, interpolation='nearest')
    ax3.title.set_text('find under 50')
    ax3.set_xticks(np.arange(len(method_list)))
    ax3.set_xticklabels(method_list)
    ax3.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
    ax3.set_yticklabels(labels)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Your plot would be easier to create via the object-oriented interface:  `fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(30,6))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 1 and 3 as the first two arguments in every call to subplot.

Docs: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html

Comment: It is working ! Thank you very much.
I had looked at the documentation before posting here. I think the base of the problem is that, even with the doc, I don't understand what the first two arguments do

Comment: They say how many rows and columns of subplots you want it to reserve space for. The 3rd argument gives the linear or ravelled index into the 2d array of subplots (but using 1-indexing, for historical reasons).